# display textOut in multiple columns using C# Console.WriteLine

Tags: c#, .net, multiple-columns, console.writeline, textout

I am creating a program that will convert Fahrenheit to Celsius and vice-versa.  The code works but how do I get my `textOut` to display in multiple columns using `Console.WriteLine` in C#?

Here is my code (not including `Program.cs` or `Input.cs`)

```
namespace Assignment2
{
    class TemperatureConverter
    {

        public void Start()
        {

            int choice = 0;

            do
            {
                DisplayMenu();
                choice = Input.ReadIntegerConsole("           Your selection: ");

                switch (choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        CalculateFahrenheitToCelsius();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        CalculateCelsiusToFahrenheit();
                        break;
                    case 0: //end session (exit loop)
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid option.  Choose between 0 and 2.");
                        break;
                }


            } while (choice != 0);
        }

        public void DisplayMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("*************************************************");
            Console.WriteLine("               MAIN MENU                     ");
            Console.WriteLine("*************************************************");
            Console.WriteLine("      Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius     : 1");
            Console.WriteLine("      Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit     : 2");
            Console.WriteLine("      Exit the Converter                : 0");
        }

        public void CalculateFahrenheitToCelsius()
        {
            double convertedValue = 0;
            string textOut = string.Empty;

            for (int i = 0; i <= 212; i += 4)
            {
                convertedValue = FahrenheitToCelsius(i);

                textOut = string.Format("{0,16:f2} F =  {1,6:f2} C", i, convertedValue);
                Console.WriteLine(textOut);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();


        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Calculate Celsius to Fahrenheit
        /// </summary>
        public void CalculateCelsiusToFahrenheit()
        {
            double convertedValue = 0;
            string textOut = string.Empty;

            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i += 5)
            {
                convertedValue = CelsiusToFahrenheit(i);

                textOut = string.Format("{0,16:f2} C = {1,6:f2} F", i, convertedValue);
                Console.WriteLine(textOut);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

        }


        private double FahrenheitToCelsius(double celsius)
        {
            double fahrenheit = (9.0 / 5.0) * celsius + 32.0;
            return fahrenheit;
        }

        private double CelsiusToFahrenheit(double fahrenheit)
        {

            double celsius = (5.0 / 9.0) * (fahrenheit - 32.0);
            return celsius;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: schoolwork?
Assignment2 is the namespace???

Comment: @AnyMoose  Yes, this is a homework assignment though putting it in columns was not part of the assignment, I am just curious how to do it :)  (the assignment is complete as is)

Comment: Your Fahrenheit and Celsius temperatures should already be aligned in columns. Can you provide an example of what you would like your output to look like?

Comment: @Dan- not sure how I can show you what I mean (comments  removes the formatting once I press enter)...I just want it to display the data in two three separate columns so that the user does not have to scroll down to see all of the values

Answer (score -2):

If all you're doing is writing lines directly out, you can create columns in one of two ways:

A) Include tabs.

```
Console.Writeline("\tColumn1\tColumn2\tColumn3");
```

B) If your Console is using a monospace font, you can count characters.  But this would be a pain in the neck.

Comment: This will only work if the contents of the columns do not exceed more than the length of one tab.

Comment: @ivcubr  Then perhaps you should pose your own solution?  If you follow the link to the duplicate question, the highest upvoted answer describes exactly the same solution. You're not offering any help here.